# What is considered the third term in a sequence that starts from 2?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have the following question...

**Consider the sequence defined by the formula $b_k=k^2$ for $k\ge2$. What is the third term in the sequence?**

I have computed the values for $k=2$, $k=3$, and $k=4$ as shown below:
$$b_2=2^2=4$$
$$b_3=3^2=9$$
$$b_4=4^2=16$$
However, I don't know what is considered the third term since $k\ge2$. Would it be 9 since you just plug in $k=3$, or would it be 16 since that's the third term if you start from 2 and count up? I haven't been able to find anything explaining how this works anywhere.

Comment: From this alone "the third term" is ambiguous terminology. I understand your confusion, but the only way to answer this would be to have more context in order to understand what the author means by "terms". For instance, if by "terms" one refers to the elements of a sequence, then the third term would be $b_3$.

Comment: I think this is a language question and not a math question.  If the sequence truly does not have a $b_1$ (nor a $b_0$) and $b_2$ is the first term then the third term is $b_4$.  But there is utterly no reason to ever say refer to it as "the third term".

Comment: Given this question, I'd say that the intended answer is "The third term is $b_4 = 16$".  And I guess I take back what I said in my first comment.  I think the book is probably trying to gently step you into the ambiguity of language and the need to think and speak precisely.  But a "third term" so literally the third term indexed and if the indexing starts and $k$ then $n$th term will be indexed by $(k-1) + n$.

Comment: It might be better to define the sequence as $a_k=(k+1)^2$ for $k\ge 1$.

Comment: I disagree with some of the comments. The sequence is: $4,\;$ $9,\;$ $16,\;$ $25,\;\ldots$ so the 1st term is $4,$ the 2nd term is $9,$ the 3rd term is $16,$ the 4th term is $25,\;\ldots$ Worrying about whether we should match "3rd term" with $k=3$ is conflating the **sequence** with a **description** of the sequence, analogous to conflating a function with some specific method of defining the function (e.g. by explicit formula or by some other method). If anything, saying the $n$'th term is $b_n$ is somewhat "math colloquial" since what $b_n$ is depends on a specific indexing of the sequence.

Answer (score -2):

I finally got the answer back from my professor, and this was the explanation I was given. The third term in the sequence is $16$. The fact that $k\ge2$ doesn't change how each term in a sequence is referred to. Therefore:
$$
\text{First term: } b_2=2^2=4
$$
$$
\text{Second term: } b_3=3^2=9
$$
$$
\text{Third term: } b_4=4^2=16
$$
Basically, the sequence still has a "first term" even though $k\ge2$, and it would still have a "second term" if $k\ge3$.